# How to distinguish which version of OpenSSL is installed?

Tags: debian, openssl, nginx

Nginx's error log shows some OpenSSL Handshake errors and while searching for the cause I found confusing outputs of what OpenSSL version is used.

```
Details:
Debian Jessie 8.7 64 Bit

# apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6
  Candidate: 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6
  Version table:
     1.0.2k-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1t-1+deb8u5 0
        500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages

# apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 1.9.10-1~bpo8+4
  Candidate: 1.10.3-1~bpo8+1
  Version table:
     1.10.3-1~bpo8+1 0
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.9.10-1~bpo8+4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.6.2-5+deb8u4 0
        500 http://mirror.hetzner.de/debian/packages/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages

# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.9.10
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)

# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
```

How can nginx runs with `openssl 1.0.2k` and o`penssl version -a` says that the Library is `OpenSSL 1.0.2k` but `apt-cache policy openssl` says installed is `1.0.1t` ?

Could someone shed some light, please?

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy nginx` output?

Comment: @StephenKitt I updated the post. The output of `apt-cache policy nginx` is really strange because I am sure that I also installed it from jessie-backports some weeks ago.

Comment: Questions like http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23799/nginx-configure-cant-find-openssl seem to indicate that nginx can be built with OpenSSL integrated as source.   Maybe yours was build that way.  Sure would be a PITA if openssl had a bug and you couldn't update it as a libarary though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`openssl`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openssl) package contains the front-end binary, not the library. You're tracking Jessie for that package (with its security updates).

The library itself is [`libssl1.0.0`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/libssl1.0.0), and you're tracking Jessie backports for that package (along with Nginx; you're just a few versions behind for the latter). This is what Nginx uses, and is the library version identified by the `openssl` front-end. You can see the version of the library on your system with

```
apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0
```

(as well as the availability of newer versions, if any).

Comment: `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` says 1.0.2k-1~bpo8+1 0 is installed. Could you please explain the difference between the front-end binary (which is version 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6) and the library? When is the binary and when the library used? Sorry if this sounds too stupid, I just want to make everything right.

Comment: The library contains the implementations of the SSL-related features (and anything else warranted by the OpenSSL API). The front-end binary provides command-line access to those features, for use interactively or in shell scripts. Other applications can use those features too, by linking to the library; this is what Nginx does. For Nginx the only thing that matters is the OpenSSL library, the `openssl` front-end isn't used.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that `nginx -V` shows which version of openssl was used to build the kernel, and that it is also showing you the version on the system that it's using.

Comment: What kernel? The operating system kernel? OpenSSL isn't used to build that.

Comment: @StephenKitt He meant NGINX.